# How to get Sitecore Profile /Pattern cards in JSON Format?

Tags: xdb

I have created few profile/pattern cards and assigned to persona. Where are these cards stored, is it in MongoDB OR SQL database?

User visit journey reaches the persona, Now I want to retrieve all the Pattern / Profile Card names into JSON format, please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

The Profile and Pattern Cards are all stored in the Sitecore SQL Databases (master and web) so you can get the list of Patterns or Profile Cards for a given Profile via the Sitecore API.

Profiles are stored under `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles` and each Profile has its own set of Profile and Pattern Cards. When you have the Items they can be cast to their respective Types with constructors or Create methods.

**Profile:** *Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ProfileItem*

```
// cast Sitecore Item to Profile
var profile = new ProfileItem(item);
```

**Profile Card:** *Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ProfileCardItem*

```
// get profile cards from a profile item
var profileCards = profile.ProfileCards;

// cast Sitecore Item to Profile Card
var profileCard = ProfileCardItem.Create(item);
```

**Pattern Card:** *Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PatternCardItem*

```
// get pattern cards from a profile item
var patternCards = profile.Patterns;

// cast Sitecore Item to Pattern Card
var patternCard= PatternCardItem.Create(item);
```

**Converting C# objects to json:**
Libraries are available to help with this. A popular one is Newtonsoft.Json which is available via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

```
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profileCardsObject);
```

It may be a good idea to select these objects into custom objects with only the properties you want in the resulting json object.